# BusinessObjects and SQL causing ORA-00936

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using BusinessObjects to write reports and I've found a SQL button that gives you the underlying query that it is running.  When I connect to the same database with my credentials and attempt to execute the same query, I get the `ORA-00936: missing expression`

Looking at the code, I see two table names separated by only spaces, (a simplified example) like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM table1  table2, table3
WHERE (conditions)
```

Is this `table1  table2` the syntax error or is this some sort of SQL `cross join` or something that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Either there's a missing comma between table1 and table2, or else table2 is a table-alias for table1...

Comment: I guess there's a missing expression in "(conditions)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `table2` is an alias for `table1`. It's simply a way to refer to the table by a different (typically  shorter) name.

Without seeing the full query, it's impossible to determine whether or not this is the source of the error.

Comment: Ah interesting, I found the error elsewhere in this meantime so this is good to know, thanks!